# Обработка события, когда "а" содержит два разных значения

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

```
shiftlist = {'fn': key, 'begin': begintime, 'end': endtime}
    ag = requests.get(URlshiftlist, headers=ST, params=shiftlist)
    string = json.loads(ag.text)
    title = string['records']
    a = [item['closeDateTime'] for item in title]
    print(a)
```

а может содержать:

> `a = [2018-02-03T15:02:57]`
>
> `a = [None]`
>
> `a = []`

```
    if a:
        URL = tlgrm
        msg = {'chat_id': 0000, 'text': '✅ ' + value + ' | Bla'}
        r = requests.post(URL, data=msg)

    if not a:
        URL = tlgrm
        msg = {'chat_id': 0000, 'text': 'ℹ️ ' + value + ' | Bla bla'}
        r = requests.post(URL, data=msg)
```

> `if a:`
> реагирует когда а = [2018-02-03T15:02:57] и а = [None]

Как сделать чтобы if a: реагировало только когда а = [2018-02-03T15:02:57] ?

Comment: вы проверяете только на наличие строки в определенном формате (дата + время)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if len(a) > 0 and a[0] is not None:...
```

Comment: Я не написал if a ... , потому что stackoverflow не разрешил сообщение с такой длиной...

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы выразить условие: контейнер и его первый элемент не пустые:

```
if seq and seq[0]:
    ...
```

Если пустые строки разрешены в вашем случае, тогда явно с `None` можно сравнить:

```
if seq and seq[0] is not None:
    ...
```

Если разрешены строки только с  датой в указанном формате:

```
import datetime as DT

try:
    DT.datetime.strptime(seq[0], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
except (IndexError, ValueError): # invalid
    pass
else:  # valid
    ...
```